# tomcat unable to publish due to deleted java.orig file

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, tomcat

I used a merge tool to merge my code with the upstream branch which created a .orig file for one of my java classes.  After verifying that everything was working fine I saw not need to keep the .java.orig file around so I deleted it.

Now whenever I try to deploy to tomcat from eclipse I get the following error:

'Publishing to Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost..' has encountered a problem.
Resource '.../MyClass.java.orig' does not exist.

I've tried removing all applications off the server and removing the server from eclipse and then recreating it but to no avail.

I'm running out of things to try and I'm not sure what dependency tomcat thinks my project has on the .orig file.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so rebooting my machine seemed to have fixed the issue I was able to start tomcat normally after that using the same eclipse workspace.  I'm not sure what the underlying issue actually was but the restart seemed to fix it.